# CUDA: device function pointer

Tags: c++, cuda

Is it possible use a function pointer with CUDA? If I have some code like:

```
__global__ void myKernel(...)
{
    int a = function(...);
}

__device__ int function(...)
{
    //do something
}
```

Could I call the function inside the kernel with a device function pointer?

Thank you!

Comment: In short: yes, they are supported, with some caveats. See the question I linked above for a description of some of the hoops you need to jump through.

Comment: Perfect, it's just what I wanted.